# Given the angles and diagonals of a quadrilateral, construct the quadrilateral using only a straightedge, a pencil, and a compass

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I tried to do this by constructing 1 angle, and then constructing 2 circles with their radii equal to the diagonals with their centres on the vertex of the angle, but I couldn't get any further from there.

This is one of the Jewish problems from the Moscow State University, but I couldn't find a solution online.

Comment: I think the problem needs more context. At what angle do the diagonals cross? See if this is of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057310/construct-quadrangle-with-given-angles-and-perpendicular-diagonals

Comment: You don't have the angle at which they intersect, which is what makes this problem so difficult